# Regex: Match all words that start with specific sign until end of the word

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

```
'@test1 in else',
'@test2 in something',
```

My goal is to receive on regex match the following:

```
test1
test2
```

The closest I got is using this but it seems to be not fully working, please help me figure it out, thanks:

```
(?<=@)(.*)(\s+)
```

Comment: I've also tried this `(?<!\w)@\w+` but it finds only the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookbehind wasn't supported in JavaScript for a long time. It's now part of the ECMAScript 2018 and supported in Google Chrome. So `(?<=@)` may not work in all Browsers.

in your example `(.*)` searches for the longest possible match (greedy) with `(.*?)` you get the shortest possible match (lazy or reluctant)

`@(.*?)\s+` or `@(\w+)` and you'll find your result in the group1 of your match.

https://regex101.com/r/JSwVOk/1

 https://regex101.com/r/JSwVOk/2

Answer (score 0):

You could use `(?<=@)(\w*)` with the `\w*` that:

> Matches any word character (alphanumeric & underscore). Only matches
> low-ascii characters (no accented or non-roman characters). Equivalent
> to [A-Za-z0-9_]

But be aware that *positive lookbehinds* are not supported in all browsers.

https://regexr.com/6tiik